# snakemake: write files from an array

Tags: snakemake

I have an array `xx = [1,2,3]` and I want to use Snakemake to create a list of (empty) files `1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt`.

This is the Snakefile I use:

```
xx = [1,2,3]
rule makefiles:
    output: expand("{f}.txt", f=xx)
    run:
        with open(output, 'w') as file:
            file.write('blank')
```

However instead of having three new shiny text files in my folder I see an error message:

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not OutputFiles
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate `output` to get filenames and then write to them. See [relevant documentation here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html?highlight=OutputFiles#how-do-i-access-elements-of-input-or-output-by-a-variable-index).

```
rule makefiles:
    output: expand("{f}.txt", f=xx)
    run:
        for f in output:
            with open(f, 'w') as file:
                file.write('blank')
```

Rewriting above rule, to parallelize, by [defining target files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) in `rule all`:

```
rule all:
    expand("{f}.txt", f=xx)

rule makefiles:
    output: 
        "{f}.txt"
    run:
        with open(output[0], 'w') as file:
           file.write('blank')
```

Comment: Thanks, @JeeYem! Is there any other way? I'm afraid that if I iterate over the output, then I won't be able to parallelize (for the more complex rules).

Comment: Please see the updated answer, which would treat creation of each file as separate jobs.